# Question on Tobit Regression

Tags: regression, censoring, tobit-regression

Does Tobit regression assume that the dependent variable is continuous above the lower bound? I am trying to model mortality (ie. "dead" or "living" but not the time) based on a set of independent variables.

Is Tobit the correct way to model it? I am familiar with logit/probit but this one has a censoring dimension to it because of the very nature of what I am trying to model.

Comment: Can you be more specific in how your variable is censored? I can't understand how you could bottom or top code a binary variable like "dead" or "alive"?

Comment: Right. I am not sure myself, I was thinking of using 0 for living and 1 for dead. The issue is that those that are alive today will die in future so I am not sure how to model this situation.

Comment: I don't think you are dealing with censored data in that case. Censoring means that your data is wither bottom or top coded (e.g. all wages below/above a threshold a coded to be some number). Would it not be more accurate perhaps to model this as some binary outcome model with a panel structure?